# how to assign integer value to string and found the sum in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Hi i have a table set like below

```
    clientId       lev1   lev2        lev3      lev4     lev5
      1            low    very-low    high      low      very-high
```

I want to map INT value for low =2 ,very-low =1 ,high =4 ,very-high =5.
then I need to find the sum for each clientId .

here I need to get (2+1+4+2+5) = 14
How can I do it ?

Comment: You mean *map*, not assign. Create a separate table with the mapping and join with it

Comment: yes i want to map . sorry for it . qus corrected.

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression and `SUM` those values.

Comment: i have done it bro . thanks for the help .

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `apply`.  In fact, you don't need `case` expressions at all:

```
select t.*, v.total
from t cross apply
     (select sum(v2.val) as total
      from (values (t.lev1), (t.lev2), (t.lev3), (t.lev4), (t.lev5)
           ) v(lev) join
           (values ('low', 2), ('very-low', 1), ('high', 4), ('very-high', 5)
           ) v2(lev, val)
           on v.lev = v2.lev
     ) v;
```

Basically what this is doing is unpivoting the levels from five columns to five rows (in the subquery).  It is then matching these to the values you have specified.  Finally, `sum()` adds them all up within a row.